# Can I create GMSPath with latitude and longitude I already have instead of pathFromEncodedPath?

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, gmsmapview

I've been following this tutorial that helps me draw route directions(polyline) between 2 tapped places on map. However I don't need to get tapped locations since by the time I want to show user the route, I'll already have latitude and longitude of origin and destination.

Can I create GMSPath with an array of latitude and longitude I already have?
If so, how..?

```
- (void)addDirections:(NSDictionary *)json {

NSDictionary *routes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"][0];

NSDictionary *route = [routes objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
NSString *overview_route = [route objectForKey:@"points"];
GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:overview_route];


GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
polyline.map = self.mainGoogleMap;}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can do it via following method.

> First you need to create **NSMutablePath** global object.
>
> Then you have to add latitude and longitude in that path like below and  then assign that path to polyline object and your polyline is drawn

**In viewDidLoad**

```
 pathDynamic = [[GMSMutablePath alloc] init];
```

**When you want to add the location in mutable path**

```
   CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[dictData valueForKey:@"fl_route_latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[dictData valueForKey:@"fl_route_longitude"] doubleValue]];
        
    [pathDynamic addCoordinate:loc.coordinate];//Add your location in mutable path
   
    GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:pathDynamic];
    // Add the polyline to the map.
    polyline.strokeColor = AppOrangeColor;
    polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0f;
    polyline.map = [self getMapView];
```

Comment: But wouldn't that just draw a straight line between 2 places..? Would that actually draw the appropriate route?

Comment: @durazno Yes draw straight line two line between two location. if you want actually route then you need the  perfect location array or encode polyline.

Comment: What do you mean by perfect location array?

Comment: @durazno **EncodedPath** is a array location which is encoded. Perfect location means each and every location come in between that two places.